# Флэшка с видеорегистратора - операционная система переходит в режим только для чтения

Tags: ос, format, sd

На видеорегистраторе автомобиля вышло сообщение о том, что SD-карта заполнена, выполните форматирование. Форматирование не делается средствами регистратора. Взяв флэшкарту домой попробовал её отформатировать на компьютере. Дома стоит Debian 12. Система на флэшке FAT. Форматировал с помощь утилиты "Диски". Дальше получилась интересная ситуация. Записываю на флэшку файл. просто текстовый. Она даёт мне записать. Даёт его изменить и сохранить. Но как только я удаляю этот файл, на флэшке появляются какие-то папки служебные. И файловая система переходит в режим "только для чтения". В частности в папке с тестовым (удалённым) файлом появился файл IndexerVolumeGuid. На одном уровне с папкой (с тестовым фалом) появилась папка .Trash-1000. В этой папке действительно мусор. Две папки и и файл с именами æ┬7₧FHEL.╣p╦ / ╦¡wß┤zvá.»⌐ / xì%┤MæJ╖.≥n2 (слэш это разделитель между именами этих файлов и папок).
Подскажите что это может быть?

```
   sudo hdparm /dev/sdc1

    /dev/sdc1:
    multcount     =  0 (off)
    readonly      =  0 (off)
    readahead     = 256 (on)
    geometry      = 59664/64/32, sectors = 122189824, start = 2048
```

- это ответ утилиты hdparm по этой флешкарте.

Comment: `SD-карта заполнена, выполните форматирование` - чаво?  а почему просто не удалить все файлы?  ну уж если хотите именно отформатировать, рекомендую сделать это в винде.  линуксовые драйвера exFAT до сих пор глючные и вряд ли это исправится в ближайшие годы.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что не даёт удалить. Сразу снимаю с видеорегистратора и пытаюсь удалить. Не даёт. Windows тоже не может форматировать. Пробовал. Возможно, регистратор ставит какую-то защиту на флэшку. Есть там такая функция, при аварии блокировать карту от стирания и записи. Но аварии не было. Ударов тоже. Пробовал удалять все разделы и снова форматировать. Выдаёт то, что описано в вопросе.

Comment: `регистратор ставит какую-то защиту на флэшку` - я уже с интересом развесил уши и слушаю вас.  как можно поставить "защиту на флешку"? )))  выхлоп от виндовой команды format запостите